# What is the internal mechanism that browsers use to process/understand HTML?

Tags: html, parsing, browser

How do browsers understand HTML?

What is the actual processing that takes place internally so that the browser renders HTML in the proper viewable way?

Comment: Really complex parsing, I guess:)

Comment: Topic is too broad I guess ;)

Comment: Yes, no-one would know the real answer to this. It's like asking "How does Google rank websites in search results?" We have theories, but no conclusive answers.

Comment: @RPM, two of the major renderers (WebKit and Gecko) are free and open source.  It's a question of devoting the time required to understand them.  Of course, just diving right in isn't always the best way to learn.

Comment: @RPM: to sum up what Matthew said: bollocks.

Comment: Okay i stand corrected, no need to chuck a hissy fit.

Comment: It'd rather look at Wikis and Blogs for introductions and discussions and overviews before going to the source code.

Comment: @RPM1984: it’s just so utterly wrong though! You seem like a smart guy, where did you get the idea from?

Comment: It was a guess, im not an expert in browser rendering. I'm sure there are areas which i have more knowledge than you. Let it go buddy. :)

Comment: @RPM1984: I’d be surprised if there weren’t. You might want to phrase your guesses as guesses though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the particular browser, but the general procedure goes something like this:

1. Read the HTML and parse it into a DOM tree.
2. Load linked resources (stylesheets, scripts, images, media)
3. Calculate the page layout (positions, sizes, colors, fonts, etc.)
4. Render the page

In modern browsers, these operations run partly in parallel, making things much more complicated than they seem.

If you want to know more details, you could look at the source code - at least Firefox (and other Gecko-based browsers) and WebKit (the basis of Google Chrome and Safari) are Open Source.

Comment: Will the browser have inbuilt Html parser ?

Comment: @Multiplexer - of course it will....

Comment: That means all the browsers will have their own parsers to parse HTML. Is it true ? Thats why the rendering of the HTML pages is little different between the browsers.

Comment: They have their own parsers, their own render engines, and their own javascript engines. Especially with Open Source browsers, parts of the functionality are used by more than one browser though: For example, Safari and Google Chrome both use the WebKit render engine.

Comment: @Multiplexer: That's part of the issue, but inconsistent rendering is mostly due to the rendering engine, not the HTML parser. SGML (and thus HTML) parsing is a fairly old problem that has been solved several times — rendering is constantly evolving and prone to bugs.

Comment: @Multiplexer: Chrome and Safari don't - they use Webkit.

Answer (score 2):

This is a larger question than it appears when first asked.

A lot goes on behind the scenes. The HTML is parsed, scripts are located, resources are loaded, some of those need to be parsed. Style sheets add to the fun. Scripts can create more work by rewriting the document as it is loaded. Somewhere along the way, the obvious security concerns must be addressed. And with every step, you have to assume that every page is a potential attempt to subvert the whole computer and defend against every attack you can think of as well as every attack you can't think of today.

And that is nowhere near a comprehensive list.

A good example with full source code available is [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko), the rendering engine behind Mozilla Firefox. It is well maintained, fast, quite standards compliant, and about as secure as 1000s of code reviewers and attackers can make it.

Answer (score 1):

It’s really not my field, but with any language, the computer has to parse it, and build an internal representation of it.

In versions of HTML before 5, each browser decided how to parse HTML itself. Starting with HTML5, the HTML spec actually defines how to parse HTML.

Not all browsers implement this yet (possibly none do), but the WebKit team at least is working on it, and looking at their work, or the HTML5 spec, might be a good place to start if you’re learning about parsing HTML.

- http://webkit.org/blog/1273/the-html5-parsing-algorithm/

Comment: There are specs for pre-5 HTML versions too. Only some browsers decided to follow them, while others didn't. Also, the spec doesn't dictate any particular parsing algorithm or technology, it merely defines the syntax and how browsers should interpret it.

Comment: @tdammers: I was under the impression that the specs for HTML 4 and earlier had nothing like the level of detail required to be considered particularly helpful for writing a parser, so effectively they didn’t define how to parse HTML. (I don’t have an opinion on that myself, as I’ve never come anywhere close to writing a parser for anything.)

Comment: @Paul, IMHO the problem was essentially that no browser ever actually followed the spec for any rev of HTML. Every browser has quirks. And patches those quirks based on the DOCTYPE, if any. HTML 4 specified itself well enough. No one cared. Install and use an HTML validator on the web at large, then try not to get depressed at how few sites pass. (This very page at SO has 24 SGML parsing errors as I type this according to the HTML Validator FF extension.)

Comment: @RBerteig: as I understood it, the HTML 4 spec, and earlier ones, didn’t define how erroneous content should be handled, whilst HTML5 does. That seems like something that would be significant to implementors (although, as I said, I’ve never written a parser for anything).

Comment: @Paul, that sharp edge only matters because essentially no web sites comply with standards. HTML5's end run around that is to declare that non-compliance as the new standard. Its a bit of a cheat, and I don't hold out a lot of hope for its full adoption either.

Comment: @RBerteig: sure. Thing is, if your goal is to get everyone in the world never making mistakes, you’re going to fail. If your goal is to get four rendering engines rendering pages the same — which I think is HTML5’s goal — then you’ve got a better chance of success. HTML5 also specifies the DOM created by documents, which I believe is more than the HTML4 specs did as well. HTML5, if I understand correctly, is significantly more detailed and useful for browser makers than HTML4 and earlier.

Comment: @Paul, I think we agree that HTML 5 is a good thing. Perhaps I've become jaded (I've actually used NCSA Mosaic over a dialup back in the dark ages of the web) and am concentrating on the warts rather than on how far things have come since then.

Comment: @RBerteig: sure. In reference to Mosaic, I really like [Mark Pilgrim’s take on standards and specs in Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.org/past.html). Browsers invent as well as follow standards. No project, double let alone programming projects, triple let alone those whose interested audience is the entire world, ever goes from idea to design to implementation to finish without going back and forth a few times.